# Sort columns next to last column in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I have multiple files:

**File 1**

```
a 1 2

b 3 2
```

**File 2**

```
a 2 2 3

b 4 3 3
```

**File 3**

```
d 3 1 2 4

e 4 1 1 2
```

I'd like to sort the files according to the column next to the last column, after sort:

**File 1**

> a **3** 2
>
> b **1** 2

**File 2**

> a 2 **3** 3
>
> b 4 **2** 3

**File 3**

> d 3 1 **2** 4
>
> e 4 1 **1** 2

I'm using awk:

```
while read line
do
cat $line|awk '{print $(NF-1)"\t"$0}'|\
         sort -n -r|awk '$1=" " {print $0}' > $line.sorted.txt
done < listfile.txt
```

Is there any better way to do that? **(Using awk, there are some problems when n (columns) is large)**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like

```
for i in f*; do
  echo "=== $i" ;
  N=$( echo $( head -1 $i | wc -w ) -1 | bc );
  sort -nrk$N $i;
done
```